# MariaDB - aggregate functions and GROUP BY dependency

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, ansi-sql

I am taking a first course on SQL since 3 weeks learned today that per SQL standards it is not possible to return the result on an aggregate function [count(*)] in the same result with listed results (like `SELECT [name] FROM [table]` unless you would add a `GROUP BY` clause on the aggregate function.

using MS SQL the instructor has demonstrated that you get an **error on an example like this**:

```
SELECT name, zip, town , COUNT(name) FROM tabEmployee WHERE department = 2 ;
```

but can get **valid result from this**:

```
SELECT name, zip, town , COUNT(name) FROM tabEmployee WHERE department = 2 GROUP BY ort ;
```

Me (on MariaDB 10.4) however get the exact same result for both queries alike. This, how we had been told, is due to MySQL/mdb being less strict in following the SQL standard (I think the term `ANSI SQL` was mentioned in that context).

I understand all that, but was wondering whether anybody could explain which benefit is behind taking a (compared to 'standard SQL') more relaxed approach?

Comment: Tip of today: The easy way, which always works, is to `GROUP BY` the columns you `SELECT` - except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. `GROUP BY name, zip, town`.

Comment: Not just less strict, but "prepare for random bad performance and random results" less strict. Don't use it

Comment: *but can get valid result from this* Only when `name`, `zip` and `town` matches  `tabEmployee.ort` (no 2 different values for the rows with the same `ort`).

Comment: Performance for this quirky syntax *has* gone down 7x times from one point MySQL 5.7 version to the next. Not even a minor version, a point version. That's because this isn't really supported and even MySQL will complain if the "newer" strict settings are used. As for randomness, if you have a group with 100 rows, which of the 100 row values do you expect to get? The "first"? There's no first without a specific ORDER BY. The server is free to return the most convenient value

Comment: thx, for the feedback. My question was, what the idea might be to create MySQL/MDN that way. I would assume that there must be a benefit, but what I take from your comments it may be just a bad design decision? Is it that what you are saying?

Comment: `but can get valid result from this` valid according to whom? You can get *something* but can't guarantee what that is. Parallelism or different join strategies can affect the order results are cached, combined and sent to the output. Without an explicit `ORDER BY` clause the server is free to send out the first value that appears. A change in the execution plan, perhaps due to changes in the data statistics, can result in different results

Comment: @vrms convenience. MySQL didn't start as a corporate RDBMS system. It didn't even have transactions until v5.0. It started as a lightweight free database meant for web sites, when websites were really small. Not OLTP and business-critical applications. No attention was paid to SQL compliance at first, with many quirks becoming unintended features. That was one of them. Remember, MySQL didn't even have transactions at first.

Comment: thanks for all the comments. Would it be then too much to say that the implied claim I've encountered in a MS dominated environment that "these open source products" may not be as 'serious' or not 'enterprise ready' may even have some sort of truth to it? And I say that from a complete pro-FOSS point of view. This would be surprising though as there are plenty of applications who rely on MySQL/mdb who definitely have at least the ambition to be 'enterprise ready'.

Comment: It is unfortunate for newcomers of SQL that MySQL/MariaDB, the only known RDBMS (open-source or not) allows that incorrect syntax in an aggregate SQL query.

Comment: Not to stray into opinionated discussion (off-topic on StackOverflow) but adamant **no** that *open-source products* are not enterprise level worthy. The world is powered by open-source. See Python, R, PostgreSQL, Linux, Apache, Android, many others!

Comment: I absolutely agree to that @Parfait. Actually pondering on this a little more I guess it's not adequate to compare things who are not the same. The thing I take from it is that you just need to accpt and learn that any `aggregate function` like the one used as an example here need the `GROUP BY` clause.